# cant start the server on port 0.0.0.0

Tags: reactjs

I have a bootstrapped React application that I want to try out on different devices. I tried setting up my ipv4 address as a host, but I got an error. Tried setting up a host like this

> "start": "set HOST=0.0.0.0 && react-scripts start"

in my packgage.js file but didn't work, I still get the error. Should I configure my firewall?

Also tried to set up the port number 80, didn't work. Here is the error log:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 0.0.0.0 PORT=80
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '0.0.0.0 PORT=80 '
}
```

This is the same error without setting up a port:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 0.0.0.0
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '0.0.0.0 '
}
```

Comment: Try `nginx` for hosting, build the React app and host it using `nginx` on default 80 port. After that you can access it over multiple devices using your local network ip

Comment: @Kaneki21 I want to run my app on any device while in dev environment.